# Error in installing PyQt

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I am following [this manual](http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/installing-pyqt-on-mac-os-x/) for installing PyQt in Mac but I got the following error:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:sip-4.16.7 mona$ sudo make install
Password:
cp -f sip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/sip
cp -f sip.so /Library/Python/3.3/site-packages/sip.so
cp -f /Users/mona/OpenSource/sip-4.16.7/siplib/sip.h /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m/sip.h
cp -f sipconfig.py /Library/Python/3.3/site-packages/sipconfig.py
cp -f /Users/mona/OpenSource/sip-4.16.7/sipdistutils.py /Library/Python/3.3/site-packages/sipdistutils.py
Monas-MacBook-Pro:sip-4.16.7 mona$ cd ..
Monas-MacBook-Pro:OpenSource mona$ ls
PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.3     sip-4.16.7
PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.3.tar.gz  sip-4.16.7.tar.gz
Monas-MacBook-Pro:OpenSource mona$ cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.3
Monas-MacBook-Pro:PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.3 mona$ python3 configure.py -d /Library/Python/3.3/site-packages/ --use-arch x86_64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 32, in <module>
    import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named 'sipconfig'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What is your python3 version: `python3 -V`?

Comment: Shouldn't you install to `/Library/Python/3.4/site-packages/`?

Comment: I was just following the manual. Can you please be more elaborative and tell me how or refer me to a less buggy manual?

Comment: That is just a guess, but the manual is for `3.3` version of python. If you installed `3.4` I would assume you have to adjust the path specified with `-d` option to match the version: `-d /Library/Python/3.4/site-packages`. Try to rebuild and install both sip and pyQt again with corrected `-d` option.

Comment: @baf Monas-MacBook-Pro:PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.3 mona$ ls /Library/Python/
2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 3.3

Comment: You have installed sip to a different version of python and executing configure.py in a different version of python. Make sure both python are same. I referred http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html to install pyqt4

Answer (score 2):

To get the new version of pyqt wich is pyqt5,  you start by installing a version of python 3.5 https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/
And you can run the command line: pip3 install pyqt5 (sometimes you will need to write it in the correct format so it will look like : pip3 install PyQt5)

Otherwise you can use brew,  first install brew :/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
And when it's done. run : brew install pyqt 
It should work